# VBA manual worksheet calculate for change event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and looking for any advice on how to manually control the change event for the below.
Column "F" has a Vlookup that returns "Fail" or "0", and rather that having each individual code to hide the row when the single cell in column F changes to 0, I found the below to work the best.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myRow As Long

If Target.Column = 6 Then
'       Loop through rows 5-160
    For myRow = 5 To 160
'           Hide row in entry in column F is "0"
        Rows(myRow).Hidden = (Cells(myRow, "F") = "0")
    Next myRow
End If

End Sub
```

I have tried to use the below with the event change but it crashes the program and always restarts. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Worksheet_Change Range("F:F")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have formulas using functions like subtotal or aggregate that hinge on hidden/visible cells? Do you have volatile functions like offset, address, today, now?

Comment: You would be better going back to single cell(s) in the worksheet_change and a static array in worksheet_calculate.

Comment: Why is `"0"` a string-that looks like a number and not a real number?

Comment: I dont have any other formulas other than vlookup which changes the cell.The "0" is just an alternative answer - I would have also left it as 'Empty' but it works either way. I just need to work out the kink to have the event change to occur when one the cell in column F is updated because they will change one at a time and not all at once.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for insights.I think I will have to go back to single cells - it's how it was set up before but wanted to see if there was a more simple code.

Comment: Perhaps but `0<>"0"` so if you looking for a numerical zero you won't find one.

Comment: Do you error control the vlookups so that you never get a #N/A error on the worksheet?

Comment: I left it as "0" because it will hide rows that have headings - these rows don't have formulas that return '0' or 'Fail'

Comment: No I don't have the error control - would this potentially make it work better?

Comment: Yes, you have to compare values and if you allow errors on the worksheet then additional error control may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of what you are trying to accomplish. If the values returned by the formulas in F5:F160 change, the changed values are caught by Worksheet_Calculate and only those changed values are processed by Worksheet_Change.

> Caveat: This method of capturing changed values from formulas does not work well when volatile functions are in the workbook. Volatile functions include TODAY(), NOW(), OFFSET(...), etc.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F5:F160")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        On Error GoTo meh
        Dim t As Range
        Debug.Print "chg: " & Intersect(Target, Range("F5:F160")).Address(0, 0)

        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("F5:F160"))
            't.EntireRow Hidden = CBool(LCase(t.Value2) = "fail" or t.Value2=0)
            t.EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(LCase(t.Value2) = "fail")
        Next t
    End If

meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static effs As Variant
    Dim f As Long, t As Range

    If IsEmpty(effs) Then
        effs = Range("F1:F160").Value2
        For f = 5 To 160
            If IsError(effs(f, 1)) Then effs(f, 1) = vbNullString
        Next f
    Else
        For f = 5 To 160
            If Not IsError(Cells(f, "F")) Then
                If effs(f, 1) <> Cells(f, "F").Value2 Then
                    If Not t Is Nothing Then
                        Set t = Union(t, Cells(f, "F"))
                    Else
                        Set t = Cells(f, "F")
                    End If
                    effs(f, 1) = Cells(f, "F").Value2
                End If
            End If
        Next f

        If Not t Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "calc: " & t.Address(0, 0)
            Worksheet_Change t
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This seems to run well on a test workbook. Additional error and looping control may be necessary in your own situation.

Comment: It works perfectly! I'm still quite new to VBA so I would have never been able to come up with an answer like yours. Again, your help is appreciated!

Comment: See my last modification.